# Create a directory with a specified path on server

Tags: c#

I have a domain path like: `https:\\lurman.gimy.y\files\\car\\`.

I'm having an exception as follows:

> The given path's format is not supported

I'm attempting to create a directory on the server using the following code:

```
public void MakeDirectory(string path)
{
    path = path.Replace("/", @"\");

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```

But I'm having the above exception. Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `https:` at the beginning of that path? If you're working with files and folders on a NAS you should be using SMB not HTTPS

Comment: (1) please provide an example of `path` value, (2) good practive is to use `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` rather than hard-coded `@"\"`
If you have path value as `http://`, you should remove `http` strings. Just make sure a path value `"files"` or `"files/car"`

Comment: But I want to create the directory on the server. How can I specify the path? 

I have the virtual path as : `https:\\lurman.gimy.y\files\\car\\`

Comment: You can only do this (securely) from the local network. With that said, you can take advantage of [SMB](https://www.samba.org/cifs/docs/what-is-smb.html) protocol using the following structure: `\\ServerName\Share\FolderOrFile`. So let's take your network path. In this case, the server name would be "lurman.gimy.y", the share name would be "files", and in that shared folder there would be a "cars" folder. It would look something like this: `\\lurman.gimy.y\files\car`. If this isn't feasible you can also try [FTP](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/ftp_for_beginners/).

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
string sPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\ApplicationDir\YourFoldername");    

 if (!Directory.Exists(sPath))
 {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
 }
```

Comment: How is this releated to the original question? Why do you think this solves the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a directory through the `http` or `https` protocol.

You can do it in your `FileSystem` or in a `shared external resource` that you can reach with a path like `\\lurman.gimy.y\files\\car\\`

Comment: But I want to create the directory on the server. How can I specify the path? 

I have the virtual path as : `https:\\lurman.gimy.y\files\\car\\`

Comment: Share the server with your machine and use the virtual path. Https isn't for sure a virtual path.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't know, it isn't a programmer know how. Usually I have a system administrator doing those things.

Comment: HTTPS is a protocol it's not part of the path. For setting up a share, check out these for [Windows/MacOS](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-share-a-folder-over-your-network-5808814) and [Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!). If this doesn't cover your OS, google search "set up smb share on [your OS]" and you should be able to find something.